# c++ function invoking order in f() + g()

Tags: c++, function

If I do like this

```
f() + g();
```

or like this

```
h(f() + g());
```

Is it guaranteed in C++ that f() is called first?

Comment: Why ask specifically for C++ in the body of the question and tag the question with C and C++??? **In C the order of evaluation is unspecified.**

Comment: If  + is not supposed to be commutative, you may think about defining your own method, less confusing than +, but then you will hit the same isssue : https://isocpp.org/blog/2016/08/quick-q-why-doesnt-cpp-have-a-specified-order-for-evaluating-function-argum

Answer (score 9, accepted):

C++ does not guarantee the order of evaluation of the operands of the `+` operator.

Either `f()` or `g()` may be called first.

This is specified by section 1.9p15 of the [C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf):

> **Except where noted, evaluations of operands of individual operators
>   and of subexpressions of individual expressions are unsequenced.** [
>   Note: In an expression that is evaluated more than once during the
>   execution of a program, unsequenced and indeterminately sequenced
>   evaluations of its subexpressions need not be performed consistently
>   in different evaluations. — end note ] The value computations of the
>   operands of an operator are sequenced before the value computation of
>   the result of the operator. If a side effect on a scalar object is
>   unsequenced relative to either another side effect on the same scalar
>   object or a value computation using the value of the same scalar
>   object, the behavior is undefined.

The best way to handle this is to execute the functions in separate statements:

```
int a = f();
int b = g();
h(a + b);
```

Comment: Thank you. Then how about this? (f()) + g();  Or is there any way to force f() to be called first?

Comment: @Zeta No difference.  Parenthesis only dictate the order in which individual operators are resolved.  It does not dictate the order of subexpressions.  For example, in `a + (b + c)`, any of `a`, `b` and `c` may be evaluated in any order, but `b + c` is evaluated before `a + (b + c)`.

Comment: @Zeta If you want `f()` to be called first, you need to do so in a separate statement.  For example `auto f_r = f(); auto g_r = g(); h(f_r + g_r);`

Comment: I found one way of doing it in one line. h((auto a = f(), a + g()));

Comment: @Zeta That syntax is not valid, and even if it were it's cumbersome to have on one line like that.  Better to break it out into multiple lines for clarity.

Answer (score 4):

There is no guarantee, according to [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/eval_order):

> The compiler will evaluate them in any order, and may choose another
>   order when the same expression is evaluated again.

Disclaimer: at least that's the case in C, I am not sure if it's the same in C++.

Edit: I just looked up the C++ version on [the same site](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), and it's also unspecified in C++.

Comment: Are you linking to a `C` resource?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I'm linking to the C subsection of a C++ resource.

Comment: and why you would do that?

Comment: There was a C tag, too, until it got removed. But good call! I'm sure the C++ answer is on the same site. I just checked, and indeed, it is.